# FlipClock Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, flipclock

I've been adding FlipClock jQuery plugin on my http://www.skivvienix.com and added html code under **"2 Pairs Starting"** =>
 `<div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>`

But my clock not working and it gives error message on Console link this:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipClock is not a function

I'm using **jquery-1.11.3** minify version. How can I solved this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Amazing anything works on that heavy page. You like miss to load the flipclock.js in all that code. Also can I just say "Euuw" to that description?

Comment: Try this syntax of init `clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'),{...}`. The jQuery version used on plugin site is v1.8.1. Check for compatibility. Also check theorder of plugin references.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me when I change jQuery( to $(

```html
<div class="clock"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3a1v57rabk2hm.cloudfront.net/skivvie/fresh-copy-4/js/flipclock.js?ts=1466140769&host=www.skivvienix.com"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clock;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var clock;

    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
      clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
      autoStart: false,
      callbacks: {
        stop: function() {
          $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
        }
      }
    });

    clock.setTime(220880);
    clock.setCountdown(true);
    clock.start();

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, it's working on backend but not on this website. Can yo help me to fixed it?

Comment: I do not have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of your scripts. `flipclock.js` shoud have loaded before the function call.

```
<script src="js/flipclock.min.js"></script>    <!-- loading flipclocjs -->
<script>
  var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(3600 * 24 * 3, {   
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
  });
</script>                                      <!-- calling function -->
```

Most probably this is the reason for all **'xxx' is not a function** errors.